# Trouble in ajax call for local files?

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova

I have used Phonegap.1.2.0.js in Window Phone 7 application. All files related html5 and javascripts are in folder called www. I have make an ajax call using jquery $.ajax({}) that call a .html file which is in www folder ( like in same folder or in local ) and it gives error "Access Denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known problem with the security policy on windows phones:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-wp7/issues/17

Comment: Thank you for your help. Access denied error is gone and i got successful first ajax-call. But there is still one problem that after first ajaxcall I load html with another ajax call in it but it doesnot work.     
Step 1.  Load document
Step 2.  Fire ajax call ( successfull with url www/example1.html )
Step 3.  Get data (with other ajax call function ).
Step 4.  Fire ajax call with other url (e.g. www/example2.html ) unsuccessfull 

I m using Phonegap-1.3.0.js with WP 7